# Como exibir asterisco em campos com required com css?

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap-3

Tenho um formulário com alguns campos obrigatórios e outros não. Como posso inserir automaticamente um asterisco no label de cada campo com *required* através do css?

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="cod_produto">Código do Produto</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cod_produto" id="cod_produto" required placeholder="Código do Produto">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="qtde_acertada">Quantidade Acertada</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="qtde_acertada" id="qtde_acertada" placeholder="Quantidade Acertada">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Para fazer com css pode adicionar uma classe (neste caso escolhi `required`) aos elementos que desejas que fiquem com o asterisco, e configurar essa classe com o [pseudo elemento after](http://tableless.com.br/como-usar-before-after/), exemplos:

Antes do `input`:

```css
.required:after {
  content:" *"; 
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
  <label for="cod_produto" class="required">Código do Produto</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cod_produto" id="cod_produto" required placeholder="Código do Produto">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
  <label for="qtde_acertada">Quantidade Acertada</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="qtde_acertada" id="qtde_acertada" placeholder="Quantidade Acertada">
</div>
```

Depois do `input`:

```css
.required:after {
  content:" *"; 
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-4 required">
  <label for="cod_produto">Código do Produto</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="cod_produto" id="cod_produto" required placeholder="Código do Produto">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
  <label for="qtde_acertada">Quantidade Acertada</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="qtde_acertada" id="qtde_acertada" placeholder="Quantidade Acertada">
</div>
```